# Pandas - aggregate group by dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with Ethereum transactions and relative internal execution calls. The data looks like the following:

```json
  [
{
"BLOCK": 12003477,
"TIMESTAMP": "2021-03-09 09:21:58.000",
"TX_HASH": "0x78fb79172b623efeebcc07d5dbf734e40890e56e8d3783ffc82b24618682f594",
"CALL_ID": "\\N",
"CALL_TYPE": "call",
"FROM_ADDRESS": "0x45ae5ae57a0f4e6250f782fc6f0daec5dead27e4",
"TO_ADDRESS": "0xf87e31492faf9a91b02ee0deaad50d51d56d5d4d",
"FUNCTION_NAME": "createEstateWithMetadata",
"ORDER_INDEX": 3859
},
{
"BLOCK": 12003477,
"TIMESTAMP": "2021-03-09 09:21:58.000",
"TX_HASH": "0x78fb79172b623efeebcc07d5dbf734e40890e56e8d3783ffc82b24618682f594",
"CALL_ID": "0",
"CALL_TYPE": "delegatecall",
"FROM_ADDRESS": "0xf87e31492faf9a91b02ee0deaad50d51d56d5d4d",
"TO_ADDRESS": "0xa57e126b341b18c262ad25b86bb4f65b5e2ade45",
"FUNCTION_NAME": "createEstateWithMetadata",
"ORDER_INDEX": 3861
},
{
"BLOCK": 12003477,
"TIMESTAMP": "2021-03-09 09:21:58.000",
"TX_HASH": "0x78fb79172b623efeebcc07d5dbf734e40890e56e8d3783ffc82b24618682f594",
"CALL_ID": "0_0",
"CALL_TYPE": "call",
"FROM_ADDRESS": "0xa57e126b341b18c262ad25b86bb4f65b5e2ade45",
"TO_ADDRESS": "0x959e104e1a4db6317fa58f8295f586e1a978c297",
"FUNCTION_NAME": "mint",
"ORDER_INDEX": 3863
},
{
"BLOCK": 12003477,
"TIMESTAMP": "2021-03-09 09:21:58.000",
"TX_HASH": "0x78fb79172b623efeebcc07d5dbf734e40890e56e8d3783ffc82b24618682f594",
"CALL_ID": "0_0_0",
"CALL_TYPE": "delegatecall",
"FROM_ADDRESS": "0x959e104e1a4db6317fa58f8295f586e1a978c297",
"TO_ADDRESS": "0x1784ef41af86e97f8d28afe95b573a24aeda966e",
"FUNCTION_NAME": "mint",
"ORDER_INDEX": 3866
},
{
"BLOCK": 12019039,
"TIMESTAMP": "2021-03-11 19:03:09.000",
"TX_HASH": "0xdabadcba08961d6fdffbdee0a5f801dd59c098b65c41087d95a608065ade712b",
"CALL_ID": "\\N",
"CALL_TYPE": "call",
"FROM_ADDRESS": "0x3b38a52998a4b786638e774007f3f8ab34db792e",
"TO_ADDRESS": "0xf87e31492faf9a91b02ee0deaad50d51d56d5d4d",
"FUNCTION_NAME": "setApprovalForAll",
"ORDER_INDEX": 1620
},
{
"BLOCK": 12019039,
"TIMESTAMP": "2021-03-11 19:03:09.000",
"TX_HASH": "0xdabadcba08961d6fdffbdee0a5f801dd59c098b65c41087d95a608065ade712b",
"CALL_ID": "0",
"CALL_TYPE": "delegatecall",
"FROM_ADDRESS": "0xf87e31492faf9a91b02ee0deaad50d51d56d5d4d",
"TO_ADDRESS": "0xa57e126b341b18c262ad25b86bb4f65b5e2ade45",
"FUNCTION_NAME": "approve",
"ORDER_INDEX": 1622
},
{
"BLOCK": 12019039,
"TIMESTAMP": "2021-03-12 20:08:20.000",
"TX_HASH": "0xbcbadcba08961d6fdffbdee0a5f801dd59c098b65c41087d95a608065ade712c",
"CALL_ID": "\\N",
"CALL_TYPE": "call",
"FROM_ADDRESS": "0x3b38a52998a4b786638e774007f3f8ab34db792e",
"TO_ADDRESS": "0xf87e31492faf9a91b02ee0deaad50d51d56d5d4d",
"FUNCTION_NAME": "setApprovalForAll",
"ORDER_INDEX": 1620
},
{
"BLOCK": 12019039,
"TIMESTAMP": "2021-03-12 20:08:20.000",
"TX_HASH": "0xbcbadcba08961d6fdffbdee0a5f801dd59c098b65c41087d95a608065ade712c",
"CALL_ID": "0",
"CALL_TYPE": "delegatecall",
"FROM_ADDRESS": "0xf87e31492faf9a91b02ee0deaad50d51d56d5d4d",
"TO_ADDRESS": "0xa57e126b341b18c262ad25b86bb4f65b5e2ade45",
"FUNCTION_NAME": "approve",
"ORDER_INDEX": 1622
}
]
```

Records with the same `TX_HASH` value belong to the same execution track. Among them, the one with `CALL_ID = \\N` represents the transaction ([etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x78fb79172b623efeebcc07d5dbf734e40890e56e8d3783ffc82b24618682f594)), and the others are the internal calls. On the internal calls records the `CALL_ID` field can get values like `0`, `0_0`, `0_1`, `0_0_0`, `0_1_0`, and so on... Each number after the underscore indicates a deeper level in the execution trace. The record with `\\N` is the actual transaction and the others represent the function executed internally by a smart contract during the execution.

Inside the dataframe, there are thousands of different transactions, and, so, thousand of different `TX_HASH` values. For each different hash value, there can be 1 or more records representing the internal calls.

Moreover, as you can see from the data sample, there is also a `FUNCTION_NAME` which indicates the function executed by the smart contract. In the case of `\\N` it indicates the top-level function, and on `0`, `0_0` indicates the internal functions.

What I need to do is to create different dataframes for each top-level `FUNCTION_NAME`, which means each different `FUNCTION_NAME` value on records with `CALL_ID = \\N`. Considering `createEstateWithMetadata` above, there should be a dataframe that contains the records that has `FUNCTION_NAME = createEstateWithMetadata` and `CALL_ID = \\N`, then considering the hashes of such records, we need to identify the internal calls (they have the same hash) and add them into the dataframe.

For instance, the dataframe for `createEstateWithMetadata` should contain the records contained in the data sample above. In the initial dataframe, there are more than 20 different values for `FUNCTION_NAME` when `CALL_ID = \\N`. An example is `setApprovalForAll` below which will lead to a new dataframe:

```json
  {
    "BLOCK": 12019039,
    "TIMESTAMP": "2021-03-11 19:03:09.000",
    "TX_HASH": "0xdabadcba08961d6fdffbdee0a5f801dd59c098b65c41087d95a608065ade712b",
    "CALL_ID": "\\N",
    "CALL_TYPE": "call",
    "FROM_ADDRESS": "0x3b38a52998a4b786638e774007f3f8ab34db792e",
    "TO_ADDRESS": "0xf87e31492faf9a91b02ee0deaad50d51d56d5d4d",
    "FUNCTION_NAME": "setApprovalForAll",
    "ORDER_INDEX": 1620
  },
  {
    "BLOCK": 12019039,
    "TIMESTAMP": "2021-03-11 19:03:09.000",
    "TX_HASH": "0xdabadcba08961d6fdffbdee0a5f801dd59c098b65c41087d95a608065ade712b",
    "CALL_ID": "0",
    "CALL_TYPE": "delegatecall",
    "FROM_ADDRESS": "0xf87e31492faf9a91b02ee0deaad50d51d56d5d4d",
    "TO_ADDRESS": "0xa57e126b341b18c262ad25b86bb4f65b5e2ade45",
    "FUNCTION_NAME": "approve",
    "ORDER_INDEX": 1622
  }
```

My idea was to first group by `TX_HASH` to get the "traces" of execution and then get the `FUNCTION_NAME` value for the first record of each group (which should be the one with `CALL_ID = \\N`) to create the dataframes and iteratively put each group in the correct dataframe. I believe that this could be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick: create a new column where the `CALL_ID` is equal to `"\\N"`, then group by `TX_HASH` and map the `TX_HASH` to the first value of the newly created column. (As there can only be one `CALL_ID=="\\N"` per `TX_HASH`.

```
df["NEW_HASH_GROUP"] = (df.CALL_ID == "\\N") * df.FUNCTION_NAME
df["GROUP"] = df.TX_HASH.map(df.groupby("TX_HASH").NEW_HASH_GROUP.first())

# Split each group in its own DataFrame
dfs = [f for _, f in df.groupby(["GROUP"])]
```

If I do:

```
for df in dfs:
    print(df.GROUP.unique())

# ['createEstateWithMetadata']
# ['setApprovalForAll']
```

Comment: I think that you considered each `FUNCTION_NAME` regardless of the `CALL_ID` value. Only the `FUNCTION_NAME` values for `CALL_ID = \\N` should lead to a new dataframe. For instance, `mint` on `CALL_ID = 0_0` shouldn't.

Comment: So then, each DataFrame should have only one row with `CALL_ID=="\\N"`, right?

Comment: Nope, I updated the question. Perhaps now is clearer.

Comment: Look at my updated answer. My reasoning is that since all transactions start from the same hash, you can first group by hash and then subdivide by the function name.

Comment: That's not totally wrong but the only function name that matters are the one when `CALL_ID is \\N`. For instance, `mint` in the third record shouldn't create a new df but should be in the df of `createEstateWithMetadata` (because it has `call_id = \\n`). Instead `setApprovalForAll` in the second example should create a new df since it has `call_id = \\n`. Your answer creates a new df also for `mint`

Comment: Ooh ok I think I get it now

Comment: Let's use the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245342/discussion-between-ypd-and-965311532)